# Invoke stored procedure with parameters inside Databricks cell using Scala

Tags: sql, scala, stored-procedures, databricks

I would like to call a stored procedure that takes a parameter with multiple values and assign the result to a val using Scala, inside a Databricks notebook cell. This is what I am thinking about:

```
val result = spark.read
.format("com.microsoft.sql.server.jdbc.spark")
.option("url", jdbcURL)
.option("user",jdbcusername)
.option("password",jdbcpassword)
.option("query", sqlQuery)
```

However I cannot figure out how to pass my parameter in the "query" option. The SQL code I have as a reference declares a parameter based on a view and inserts the desired parameter values into that like this:

```
DECLARE @rc int
DECLARE @p_list something.some_name

INSERT INTO @p_list
SELECT 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5',

EXECUTE @rc = something.stored_procedure
@p_list
GO
```

Could someone provide a hint on how could this be done? Please tell me if it is unclear